# How to keep the state?

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

```
ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _list.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, i) {
            return ListTile(
              title: todonoteShow(context, _list[i]),
              leading: IconButton(
                icon: _list[i].isDone == true
                    ? Icon(
                        Icons.radio_button_checked,
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      )
                    : Icon(Icons.radio_button_unchecked),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _list[i].isDone = !_list[i].isDone;
                  });
                },
```

here is my code, when i click the button, the state is change, it's right,

**but after i open another page,and comeback, the icon's state is reset,,**

i use sqflite, my question is when i click the iconbutton,

how can i save the parameter *_list[i].isDone*  to my database ,

thankyou !

```
database//
 final String columnIsDone = 'isDone';

Future<int> updateTodo(Todonote todonote) async {
    var d = await db;
    var res = d.update(tableName, todonote.toMap(),
       );
    print('$res');
    return res;
  }

todo.dart//
_saveTodo1(String thing, bool isDone) async {
    if (widget.todonote != null) {
      Todonote upd = Todonote.fromMap({
        'id': widget.todonote.id,
        'thing': widget.todonote.thing,
        'isDone': isDone == true ? 1 : 0
      });
      await widget.db.updateTodo(upd);
      return upd;
    }
  }

iconbutton//
 onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _list[i].isDone = !_list[i].isDone;
                      });
                      _saveTodo1(_list[i].thing, _list[i].isDone);
                    },
```

i did like above, but it doesn't work !

```
class DataBase {
  Database _database;
  final String tableName = 'notetodo';
  final String columnId = 'id';
  final String columnThing = 'thing';
  final String columnIsDone = 'isDone';
  final String tableName2 = 'notetodo2';
  final String columnId2 = 'id2';
  final String columnTitle = 'title';
  final String columnThing2 = 'thing2';
  final String columnDate = 'date';

  initDb() async {
    var directoryPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    String path = join(directoryPath, 'notetodo.db');
    var db = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
    print('good，version:1');
    return db;
  }

  FutureOr<void> _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute('''create table $tableName(
            $columnId integer primary key,
            $columnThing text not null,
            $columnIsDone integer)''');
    await db.execute('''create table $tableName2(
            $columnId2 integer primary key,
            $columnThing2 text not null,
            $columnDate text not null,
            $columnTitle text)''');
    print('right');
    db.close();
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IymU1.png)

Comment: have you looked at Shared Preferences?

Comment: @F-1 i've heard little about Shared Preferences, but i dont know is it enough to storage data for todo App?

Comment: I see, you will need to add a new column to your database that stores your boolean values. Then whenever the onPressed button is called the boolean value is changed from it's current value to the opposite. A call to your database to save the data. Then set state as you have done should work (remember if you change your database you'll need to do a fresh install of the app)

Comment: @F-1 yes ,i have the column,wait ,i add some code above.

Comment: If your database is saving the new value without throwing an exception then this should work. Are you able to check the device database? Are you using a FutureBuilder to retrieve your data from the database to then build your listview?

Comment: @F-1 you mean in the iconButton should have 2 method ,one is a FutureBuilder to retrieve your data from the database , another one to build the listView ??

Comment: Is the data for your button in a different table to that of your listview data? I was thinking FutureBuilder to retrieve the data then the snapshot is used to create the listview.

Comment: @F-1 hello, i have upload a picture about my app, you can see, the iconbutton is the leading in the ListTile,  it's be controll of the parameter isDone ,it is in a same table, and what is snapshot you say? it is hard to understand to me ? do you have Learning document of that ?  and i have a new question is that i want to make a new table ! but i fail, there is a exception says there have not column: id2..

Comment: Here is info on FutureBuilder https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html and here is a tutorial https://medium.com/@jimmyhott/using-futurebuilder-to-create-a-better-widget-4c7d4f52a329. Where the author uses future: firebase...' you use your database call e.g 'future: fetchFromDatabaseMethod()'. After the method is run the Futurebuilder waits for the data to be returned, the data is stored in 'snapshot.data' as you'll see in the guide, you then use this to create your listview.

Comment: @F-1 thank you man, it's really really helpful, love you ..

Answer (score 0):

I used firebase's firestore to store my data for Google keep's clone, When I needed to change the button (In label selected or not ) I Created a label tag with true and false value and whenever I change the data I change it inside the firestore.

Comment: That seems like taking a sledgehammer to crack a nut, wouldn't shared preferences be better to handle such small data sets?

Comment: Said I was using firebase for the whole data and since Label isn't just about icon status I was also saving the name of the label and which note it is assigned to. So yea it was not just a nut. Anyway, I just shared what I did, shared pref would work and also the SQflite.

Comment: my mistake, seems like OP just needs to add a new column to their database to store the boolean values.

Comment: @SarthakSolanki thanks for your answer, i will study firestore after i have know about Sqflite..